# Retrieve chat log during game

Tags: league-of-legends

I am trying to develop an application that needs to retrieve the ingame chat during your own game.
This can't be done by storing my own inputs because I want to retrieve game chat from all players in my team (so just the team chat).
I have tried to use tesseract to read the text from an image but this doesn't retrieve the correct text. It does not recognize all the characters or only recognizes parts of a sentence/word.
Is there a way to retrieve the chat messages or correctly get the exact text from an image?

Comment: I think it is impossible (AKA extremely difficult). LoL does not seen to expose any sort of chat API or save chat logs to file anywhere. That being said, it might be possible by sniffing the network packets (unlikely to succeed since they are probably encrypted), or directly accessing some memory locations (could potentially be detected as an attempted exploit or hack). Hopefully someone knows something I don't.